# MS Access: If I have imported data from maximo in a table, can I still add my own fields in the same table?

Tags: ms-access, peoplesoft

I have a table in Access called tbl_employees and I think most if not all of the information from this table is imported from PeopleSoft, but if I wanted to add my own fields to this same table (I want to add a Yes/No field (checkbox), a textbox field and an attachment field), would it have a negative impact on the data? Like would it stop updating it correctly? Let me know if this doesn't make sense. Thank you!

Comment: If nobody gives you an answer, consider trying your own experiment: Make a copy of your db (and/or maybe zip your db) and try adding your own columns. If it doesn't work-out, you can safely undo, or switch back to the original.  Maybe make 2 backups, just in case.

Comment: You could play it safe by creating an "extension" table with the same key as the tbl_employees and the additional fields you want to add.

Comment: Normally data can be imported to a table that has more fields than the source. I don't see why it would be different with PeopleSoft product. Try it.

Comment: It should be fine if you are just adding stuff on the MS Access side.